# How to change escaping of single quotes with Mysqldump for Postgres format?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mysql

I use mysqldump to save data from tables and move it to Postgres db.
I make dump with:

```
mysqldump --complete-insert --no-create-info --no-create-db --compatible=postgresql -uroot -p music files > music_files.sql
```

But while doing in `psql`:

```
=> \i music_files.sql
```

have this error:

```
music_files.sql:29: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s"
LINE 1: ...,5,'Impossible',NULL),(33,4103,178,841,198,'Tifa\'s Theme [P...
```

Postgres doesn't understand this escaping. It wants 2 quotes `''` before `s`
How can I make it with mysqldump?

Comment: You could try `--compatible=ansi`

Comment: @fvu, doesn't work for me, still \' escaping

Comment: sorry to hear that, apparently these `--compatible` settings are not that compatible after all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in the `psql` shell:

```
=> set backslash_quote = on;
=> set standard_conforming_strings = off;
=> select 'foo\'bar';
 ?column? 
----------
 foo'bar
=> \i ...whatever...
```

Do *NOT* make this persistent by setting it in some configuration file or by `ALTER USER` etc. since this may be security relevant.